# ZF2 - how to check if a route with child exists

Tags: zend-framework

Given this route:

```
    'country' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/1country',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action'     => 'country',
                    'country_id'     => '5',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                        'city' => array(
                            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/1city',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Index',
                                    'action'     => 'city',
                                    'city_id'     => '4',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),

             ),
        ),
```

if I do:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Router')->hasRoute('country'); //true
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Router')->hasRoute('country/city'); //false
```

While both should be true.. Any ideas?

Comment: Why need such behavior?

Comment: is complex to explain, but basically I have seo optimized routes and not seo optimized routes, no seo optimized routes will redirect with 301 to optimized seo routes if they exist.Anyway I found out the solution by doing if hasRoute, get, and then do the hasRoute on that parent route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// explode if child..  
$route = 'home/default';  
$names = explode('/', $route, 2);

// use
/* @var Router $router */
$router = $container->get('Router');

if (!$router->hasRoute($names[0])) {
   // ...
}
```